# Java generic array type that also supports long[]?

Tags: java

Suppose I want to have a class for polynomials:

```
public class Polynomial<T> {
    private T[] coefficients;
}
```

where I need to store the coefficients in an array. I want this array to be as fast as possible, so for most of the cases, I'd like it to be a `long[]`. However, I'd also like to support some cases where it is a `BigInteger[]` array.

I've been reading about generic arrays in [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) and it looks like this case:

```
public class GenSet<E> {

    private E[] a;

    public GenSet(Class<E> c, int s) {
        // Use Array native method to create array
        // of a type only known at run time
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final E[] a = (E[]) Array.newInstance(c, s);
        this.a = a;
    }

    E get(int i) {
        return a[i];
    }
}
```

would not work for `long`. Maybe I'd have to use `Long`, for which I'd have some performance penalties I guess. The unchecked case, on the same answer, is even worse as things are just an `Object`.

Comment: Generics cannot be used asprimitives (except wrappers). That's it.

Comment: " I want this array to be as fast as possible, so for most of the cases, I'd like it to be a long[]. However, I'd also like to support some cases where it is a BigInteger[] array." biginteger and long don't have much in common. Are you really sure you want to have both in a same array? That will have plenty of perf penalties.